# xPath that selects elements between two specific sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml and I need to select the only b's having type "desc" under the element having type of "header".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x>
<a>
   <b type="header" text="A." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="desc" text="A1." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="desc" text="A2." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="desc" text="A3." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="desc" text="A4." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="header" text="B." />
</a>
<a>
   <b type="desc" text="B1." />
</a>
```

Code should be something like that:  `/x/a/b/[@type='desc']....`

output must be:

```
A1.
A2.
A3.
A4.
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
/x/a[following-sibling::a[b[@type='header']] and preceding-sibling::a[b[@type='header']]]/b[@type='desc']/@text
```

Comment: This works but when I put another header below B1. it will not give the same output.

Comment: Hmm... I don't get why you expect the same output when another header added below B1. In that case, B1 is between two headers so it will be in the output list..

Answer (score 1):

```
/x/a/b[@type="header"]/../following-sibling::*[0][name()='a']/b[@type="desc"]/@text
```

Untested but you find the header, go back up to a, take the first following element, check that it's an a, then look for a child of b, type desc and take the text attribute.
......

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for reply but the query returns error like: "Namespace with prefix 'following-sibling' has not been declared."

Comment: Missed a colon. Code changed but you can see what's happening.

Comment: I have tested but this one gives no match.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been following-sibling::*[1]. However, at least in xsltproc, it only returns the first match so, while it should work in theory, apparently the implementation does not.

Answer (score 1):

By default XPath uses the children axis, but in this case you need to check the preceding and following siblings.

First you need to specify the starting `a` node. It has to contain an `b` node of the `type` `header` and with the `text` `A.`.

`a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]]`

It has to be a preceding sibling of the nodes you want to fetch.

`preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]]`

The second limit is the first following sibling of this node with the `type` `header`:

`preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]]/following-sibling::a[b[@type="header"]][1]`

Next make it a condition for the `a` nodes. So you select only nodes between these two:

```
/x/a[
   preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]] and 
   preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]]/following-sibling::a[b[@type="header"]][1]
  ]
```

Last select the `text` attribute nodes of `b` child nodes with the `type` attribute `desc`

```
/x/a[
   preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]] and 
   preceding-sibling::a[b[@type="header" and @text = "A."]]/following-sibling::a[b[@type="header"]][1]
  ]/b[@type = "desc"]/@text
```

Comment: That's fine but I have got only one parameter which is the header text of the "A." so I do not have the info about the following header in my query. Thanks anyway...